# magento2 check if order invoiced or shipped

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to check if the order is shipped or invoiced by store owner from order object.

```
$this->registry->registry('current_order');
```

I have current order object, I want to know if its been shipped or invoiced

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if ($order->getInvoiceCollection()->count()) {
    // Invoice exist.
}

if ($order->getShipmentsCollection()->count()) {
    // Shipment exist.
}
```

Alternatively you can also do by,

```
$order->hasInvoices() // For Invoice

$order->hasShipments() // For shipment
```

Where `$order` is the current order object